# Is it correct to use the term "Jumbo" when referring to any packets > 1500 bytes, even those created in software by LRO

Tags: jumboframes

I can be a bit of a stickler for correct terminology at work.

Recently we have been dealing with the effects of [Large Receive Offload](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_receive_offload) on our application. To 
quote wikipedia

> It works by aggregating multiple incoming packets from a single stream into a larger buffer before they are passed higher up the networking stack, thus reducing the number of packets that have to be processed.

I have heard people at work refer to these as Jumbo packets.  I am aware of [Jumbo Frames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumbo_frame) in Ethernet.  I think there could be confusion because Jumbo Frames are about what flows on the physical network - they affect the MTU, whereas LRO is only in the software layer and the MTU hasn't changed.

Is it correct to refer to any packet over 1500 bytes as a Jumbo packet, regardless of whether it was flowing on the physical network or not?

Answer (score 0):

"Jumbo" should only refer to data on the wire. Once the NIC has collected the packets it does not pass something that looks like a Jumbo Frame up the stack, it only passes a buffer to a kernel driver. It generally only works on TCP steams, and requires the NIC to work at OSI level 3 to process the packets.

Comment: This sounds correct to me.  It would be nice to have some references to back that up.  I wonder if there is a standards document, an RFC or equivalent for Ethernet that makes use of the term Jumbo.